# getting error message "fatal: Not a git repository" on entering command "git remote -v"

Tags: git, github, fatal-error

I cloned my github repository in my home directory using the command "git clone https://github.com/username/filename.git" .

The command ran successfully but when I run "git remote -v" , I get the following error message:
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

How can I fix this? I am using OSX.

Comment: Did you `cd` into the cloned repository first?

Answer (score 0):

After you clone, do:

```
cd filename
```

where `filename` is the name of the repo, which was `filename` in the url you mentioned.

Comment: cd filename does not solve the problem