# My Git repository is suddenly reporting "fatal : not a git repository"

Tags: git, github

When I type git status I get the following:

fatal: not a git repository: xx/static/vendor/bootstrap/../../../../.git/modules/xx/static/vendor/bootstrap

which is not even the folder I am in but for some reason thinks I am.

Here is the contents of my .git folder:

```
FETCH_HEAD
HEAD
ORIG_HEAD
branches
config
description
hooks
index
info
logs
objects
packed-refs
refs
```

Other stackoverflow pages I have investigated:

I looked at [How to "resolve fatal: Not a git repository"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718822/how-to-resolve-fatal-not-a-git-repository) but I don't have a modules folder as in that solution.

Also [getting error message "fatal: Not a git repository" on entering command "git remote -v"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519637/getting-error-message-fatal-not-a-git-repository-on-entering-command-git-rem) did nothing at all.

I am expecting "git status" to produce a normal report.

Comment: Verify that you are still inside your Git project's folder.

Comment: *which is not even the folder I am in but for some reason thinks I am* ... so, ... what folder *are* you in?

Comment: Looks like you are using submodules, and `git status` attempts to report the status of one of them (perhaps recursively), but something is wrong with the submodule.

Comment: Where would I find the submodules config file?  I wonder if I used a submodule on it maybe some time ago and abandoned it

Comment: I am in top level project directory.  The one that contains .git as a sub folder.

Answer (score -4):

in your project folder. execute git init.
git remote add origin "git repository url"
and then check that "git status"

Comment: It should not be necessary to use `git init` - the OP is saying the repository *already exists*.

Comment: Yeah. But I think he didn't set that in the local

Comment: @RoyalWebGuru, what do you mean by "I think he didn't set that in the local"? It doesn't make sense.